# Разбор слов по составу: рисовать и лавировать

Tags: морфемика

На одном ресурсе приводится **разный разбор этих слов**: рис/ова/ть и лавирова/ть, а почему? Оба слова являются **непроизводными**.

[онлайн — разбор слова по составу (морфемный разбор) | morphemeonline.ru](http://morphemeonline.ru/%D0%9E/%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD)

Comment: а почему по ссылке разбор слова *онлайн*?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, зачем нужны эти сайты-роботы, выполняющие работу по плохому алгоритму? Есть же словари нормальные: и морфемные, и словообразовательные...

Корень *рис* очень даже производный: *за/рис/ов/к/а, вы/рис/ов/а/ть, пере/рис/ов/а/ть*! Слово членится так: рис/ов/а/ть (ср. *рис/ов/**а**/льн/ый, рис/ов/**а**/нн/ый*).

Лавиров/а/ть (ср. *лавиров/**а**/ниj/е, лавиров/**а**/нн/ый*).

*Использовались материалы "Школьного словаря строения слов русского языка" З. А. Потихи и "Словаря морфем русского языка" А. И. Кузнецовой и Т. Ф. Ефремовой.*

P. S. Они там в описании к сайту рассказывают сказки, что якобы словарь Кузнецовой использовали... так вот я вам реальную информацию из словаря о *рисовать* привел. А сайты эти со стотысячным словником, по-моему, халтура полная.

Comment: А почему неправильно лавир/ова/ть - лавир/у/ю, чередование в суффиксе ОВА/У?

Comment: @Sibylla допустим, вы выделили корень *лавир*. Объясните, что делать с частью *ов*? В каких однокоренных словах она пропадает, и остается корень *лавир*? (NB: именно в словообразовании!)

Comment: В форме глагола "лавирую" нет форманта ОВ., чередование ОВА на У. Или там чередование ОВ+А на У, странное такое чередование части основы и суффикса.

Comment: Может, и напишет, только мне кажется, что структура слов одинаковая: рисовать/рисую - рисование, лавировать/лавирую - лавирование. Просто у "рисовать" словообразовательное гнездо  значительно больше. Кстати, "рисовать" заимствовано из польского языка в 18 веке, исконным его тоже не назовешь.

Comment: @Sibylla эврика! я совсем забыл, тут чередование, как вы пишете, только *ов/у* — это совершенно нормально в гл. *рисовать*. Но в *лавировать* мы не можем обосновать выделение суф. *ов*, поэтому о чередовании, наверно, речи быть не может.

Comment: @Sibylla хотя знаете, может, это и нормально, что тут *ов* относят к корню, и он чередуется. Как бы понятно, что это должен быть суф., но из-за того, что его нельзя выделить, он считается частью корня.

Comment: Знаете, мне кажется, что суффикс ОВА/ЕВА  с чередованием на У/Ю -  это глагольная морфема (регулярная и продуктивная), то есть она используется часто и с ее помощью в современном языке образуются новые глаголы. Нет никакой необходимости присоединять ее к корню, в том числе в непроизводных словах, так как в дальнейшем при образовании новых слов суффикс ОВА/ЕВА может усекаться частично или полностью.

Comment: @Sibylla это уже дело подходов, кажется. По-моему, мы не можем найти слова (!), а не словоформы, где есть корень *лавир*.